# Total market cap in country, and average p/e per country and continent(europe)

Tags: historical-data, historical-analysis, price-earnings-ratio, market-capitalization

sorry I am not sure to post this question in quant stackexchange or in here. I have posted it previously in the below link https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18633/total-market-cap-in-country-and-average-p-e-per-country-and-continenteurope

I want to invest my monthly saving on index fund. However, I am not sure to pick which country index fund that I want to invest. I am afraid i am investing in an index fund that is so overvalued goes over the roof and haven't manage to come back after such a long time like nikkei 1989 or 1929 or Nasdaq in 2000 maybe?

I just read the article about Warren Buffett indicator that says something like the ratio of gdp compare to the total market cap per country helps to define whether the stock market is overvalued or not for that country. I also hear a lot that the average p/e ratio of the market helps to define whether the market is overvalue or not.

In my place, I have an access to invest with an index fund in the following market: China, Hongkong , SIngapore, US, Europe, taiwan, SOuth Korea, Japan, Australia, India, Russia, Brazil.

My question is, where can I get the historical total market cap, GDP and average p/e of the market for those countries above? This really helps me to allocate my saving and prevent investing my money in an overvalued market.

i have had a look at http://mebfaber.com/ as written in [Where can I find P/E and CAPE data for different sectors, countries and market capitalizations](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23977/where-can-i-find-p-e-and-cape-data-for-different-sectors-countries-and-market-c) but unable to find what i want to look for.

Thanks heaps.